# ClassNotFoundException in CacheJdbcStoreExample run on cluster

Tags: ignite

I have a cluster with 2 nodes. Then I tried to run the CacheJdbcStoreExample  in apache-ignite-fabric-2.1.0-bin/examples.But I got following exception:

```
visor> [06:51:41,113][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#13%null%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to unmarshal discovery custom message.
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes or enable pee
r-class-loading) [clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4aa4ceeb, cls=org.apache.ignite.examples.datagrid.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcStoreExample$1] at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:124)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:94)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:143)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9733)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.messages.TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.message(TcpDiscoveryCustomEventMessage.java:81)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.notifyDiscoveryListener(ServerImpl.java:5436)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processCustomMessage(ServerImpl.java:5321)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2629)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.processMessage(ServerImpl.java:2420)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerAdapter.body(ServerImpl.java:6576)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2506)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.examples.datagrid.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcStoreExample$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8465)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.resolveClass(JdkMarshallerObjectInputStream.java:54)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1817)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1711)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1982)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1917)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1527)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2227)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2151)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2009)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2227)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2151)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2009)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2118)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2009)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2227)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2151)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2009)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2227)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2151)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2009)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1533)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:420)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:121)
    ... 12 more
```

I decompiled CacheJdbcStoreExample$1.class and got following code:

**CacheJdbcStoreExample$1**

```
package org.apache.ignite.examples.datagrid.store.jdbc;

import javax.cache.configuration.Factory;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.store.CacheStoreSessionListener;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcStoreSessionListener;
import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool;

class CacheJdbcStoreExample$1
  implements Factory<CacheStoreSessionListener>
{
  public CacheStoreSessionListener create()
  {
    CacheJdbcStoreSessionListener lsnr = new CacheJdbcStoreSessionListener();

    lsnr.setDataSource(JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:ExampleDb", "sa", ""));

    return lsnr;
  }
}
```

SO I think there is something wrong at row 90 in **CacheJdbcStoreExample** source code:

```
// Configure JDBC session listener.
cacheCfg.setCacheStoreSessionListenerFactories(new Factory<CacheStoreSessionListener>() {
    @Override public CacheStoreSessionListener create() {
        CacheJdbcStoreSessionListener lsnr = new CacheJdbcStoreSessionListener();

        lsnr.setDataSource(JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:ExampleDb", "sa", ""));

        return lsnr;
    }
});
```

If I run the example on only one node not a cluster, it's OK.

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you configured a cache with a factory of `CacheStoreSessionListener`-s, but this factory is not visible from other nodes as they don't have it in their classpath.

You should start additional remote nodes with `org.apache.ignite.examples.ExampleNodeStartup` class from examples module or add examples module to the classpath of other nodes.

Comment: Do you mean that the factory class could not be loaded by PeerClassLoading? In my real case, the factory class need to be created dynamicly, so other nodes do not have the factory class before running. In other words, I don't understande what class can be p2p loaded and what can not.

Comment: As per the documentation, only tasks and closures may be loaded over p2p: https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.1/docs/zero-deployment
You can add factories dynamically, it is only required that classes that you use for it are visible from all nodes.

Comment: OK,I see.Thanks for your help.